# How to get the Song ID, Album ID and Artist ID from the currently playing song from the google play music

Tags: android

I am working on my app in which i want to get the details of the songs playing on any media application.
I am not getting the data of the Google Play Music apps currently playing songs details like song id, artist id, album id.

I have tried below code:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();

        intentFilter.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.spotify.music.playbackstatechanged");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.spotify.music.metadatachanged");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.apple.android.music.metachanged");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.apple.android.music.playstatechanged");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
        intentFilter.addAction("com.rdio.android.playstatechanged");

        //register the intentfilters into the reciever
        registerReceiver(mReceiver,intentFilter);
```

Here is my Reciever:

```
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            //Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

            String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
            Log.v("tag ", action + " / " + cmd);

            //not getting the song id in the google play music and album_id and artist id in both
            final String song_id=String.valueOf(intent.getLongExtra("id", 0));
            final String album_id= String.valueOf(intent.getLongExtra("album_id",0));
            final String artist_id= String.valueOf(intent.getLongExtra(MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID,0));
            final String title=intent.getStringExtra("track");
            final String playlist_id= String.valueOf(intent.getLongExtra(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID,0));
            final String playlist_name=intent.getStringExtra(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME);
            final String artist=intent.getStringExtra(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST);
            final String album=intent.getStringExtra(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM);
        }
    };
```

Getting the songs details in the default player but not in google play music.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers are only kinda correct but not fully here's the actual answer to that question: PlayMusic has it's own content provider you can query.

Here's a working example (trackId is the SongId extra from the intent):

```
private void loadPlayMusicSongDetails(Context context, String trackId){
    String artistName = null;
    String albumName = null;
    String trackName = null;
    long year = 0;

    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.YEAR,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM_ID,
            PLAY_MUSIC_COLUMN_ARTWORK_LOCATION,
            //"artworkUrl",
            //"VThumbnailUrl",
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns._ID };

    Uri gMusicUri = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/audio");

    try {
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(gMusicUri, Long.parseLong(trackId));
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                proj, null, null, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE);
            int artistColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST);
            int albumColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM);
            int yearColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.YEAR);
            int albumArtColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(PLAY_MUSIC_COLUMN_ARTWORK_LOCATION);

            trackName = cursor.getString(titleColumn);
            artistName = cursor.getString(artistColumn);
            albumName = cursor.getString(albumColumn);
            year = cursor.getLong(yearColumn);
            String albumArtLocation = cursor.getString(albumArtColumn);

            if(albumArtLocation != null && albumArtLocation.length() > 0){
                if(albumArtLocation.startsWith("mediastore:")){
                    long albumId = Long.parseLong(albumArtLocation.substring(albumArtLocation.indexOf(":")+1));
                    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
                    setAlbumArtUri(ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumId));
                }
                else {
                    //TODO: perform http calls if you wanna query for online images
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting song id,artist id and album id you should use this method. From that you can get it.

```
       ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            audioList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String data  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String album_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                Long albumid = Long.parseLong(album_id);
                Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
                Uri finaluri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumid);
                String path = FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), finaluri);
                //Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                // Save to audioList
                audioList.add(new Audio(data, title, album, artist,path));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I read a blog before,Give you a thought, I have not tried, but the feeling should be able to achieve.

1.when the next music is played, the app will be broadcast and the broadcast will contain the next song's information;

2.for example:Android system's music player will send with "com.android.music.metachanged" broadcast;

3.registerReceiver

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
registerReceiver(Your Receiver, intentFilter);
```

4.Analysis of intent,You can get this information from the intent

```
intent.getStringExtra("album");
intent.getStringExtra("artist");
intent.getStringExtra("track");
intent.getStringExtra("notify_artistname");
intent.getStringExtra("notify_audioname");
```

5.I do not know if Google Play Music will send a broadcast,also,I'm not sure about Google Play Music's IntentFilter.

6.Wish you success!

Answer (score -1):

You need to read Id3Tag to get this information, here is some documentation for [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html). You can use it to work with Id3Tag in Android.

Usage example:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(filePath);
String albumName = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
```

Comment: I am getting the name of the album using the metadata but i am not getting the album art, and album id of the play music.

Comment: What API do you use?